# HTML Imported text doesn't show line feeds correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML file which has an included text file. This is my javascript for including text file:

```
document.include = function (url) {
    if ('undefined' == typeof(url)) return false;
        var p,rnd;
        if (document.all){
        p = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    else {
        p = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    rnd = Math.random().toString().substring(2);
    url = url.indexOf('?')>-1 ? url+'&rnd='+rnd : url+'?rnd='+rnd;
    p.open("GET",url,false);
    p.send(null);
    document.write( p.responseText );
};
```

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link media="all" href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Report</title>
        <script src="embed_text.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>document.include('out.log');</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately imported content does not have any line feed! All lines are appended to each other; but when I go to inspect mode, all lines are showing correctly! I mean content is showing in separate lines. What should I do to solve the problem. Solutions including CSS or javascript are completely fine!

This is how content differs in HTML view and inspect mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this code to your html:

```
<style>
    body {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
</style>
```

More about white spacing:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

If there are other components in your html body, not just text from log, then wrap it in a div and change rule selector.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your code is being parsed as HTML, and thus new lines and spaces beyond the first are being removed.

Try wrapping your text within `<pre>` tags, and you should see the desired output.

Comment: Your answer worked too, but since @Vilimantas's answer was more general, I used that as the solution.

Comment: What do you mean more general?

Comment: I mean it's linked to a standard! Besides using CSS is more preferable to me, because I use a script to automatically generate the HTML and having less tags is more efficient!

Comment: So you're saying I should have linked you here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp :P

Comment: Your link was really helpful! I really appreciate your help! But focus on the second section of my last comment please! :-)